# How to transfer data between SwiftUI views

Tags: json, swift, url, swiftui

Hello all) Please tell me this question, I can not figure out how to do it right. There is the first screen it has 4 pictures with the name of each picture, when you click on the picture throws to the next screen, the question is how to correctly pass the name of the different pictures on the other screen. What exactly should be transferred to NavBarMenuView? When trying to pass a model to NavBar, the error Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'FoodCategory'. FoodCategory is a model  I send the data via JSON

```
struct NavBarMenuView: View {
    var categoryViewModel: FoodСategory
    
    var body: some View {
        
        HStack {
            
            Button {
      
            } label: {
                Image(systemName: "chevron.left")
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
            }

            
            Spacer()
            
            Text(categoryViewModel.name)
                .font(.callout)
            
            Spacer()
            
            Image("avatar")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .frame(width: 44, height: 44)
        }
        .padding(.horizontal, 20)
    }
}

struct MenuView: View {
    @StateObject var menuViewModel = MenuVieiwModel()
    @StateObject var categoryTitleVM = CategoriesViewModel()
    //@State var titleText: [FoodСategory] = []
    
    @State var showDetail = false
    
    var columns = Array(repeating: GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: 15), count: 3)
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            
            NavigationView {
                
                VStack {
                    
                    NavBarMenuView()} //Erro Missing argument for parameter 'categoryViewModel' in call
}
```

I tried to pass the model to NavBarMenuView, but it generates an error Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'FoodCategory'. FoodCategory is a model

Comment: OK, `FoodСategory` is a model, but where does it come from?

Comment: Try to see some SwiftUI tutorials to understand your problem. When you declare a var in a view with no initial value, it means that the caller view must call it with a parameter whose name is the name of the var and the value passed must be of the same type.

Comment: Vadian, A little confused about the question?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as well as [Apple’s SwiftUI tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/SwiftUI).

Answer (score 0):

You're over complicating it with objects, it should be just:

```
struct NavBarMenuView: View {
    let name: String

    ...     
            Text(name)
                .font(.callout)
```

```
NavBarMenuView(name: model.name)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! It was easier than I thought it would be))))